# Separate touchpad sensitivity

Tags: mouse, laptop, trackpad, cursor

For gaming precision on PC, I have disabled mouse acceleration. The mouse speed works as I wanted to, however the touchpad is just too slow.

Is there a way to have separate cursor speed for mouse and trackpad? I prefer no acceleration at all

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not possible in the current version of Ubuntu. You might, however, want to take a look at / contribute to this thread on Ubuntu Brainstorm: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/6030